# Javascript modal draggable popup

Tags: javascript, popup, draggable, modal-dialog

Maybe someone knows where can I find some SIMPLE JavaScript code for Draggable Modal Popup Window like http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
Microsoft AJAX is too heavy, jquery needs to include many js files include whole jquery core and css. I need something very simple - include one js file to show hidden div's content with blocked background.

Answer (score 1):

try the blockUI plugin

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

probably that one isnt draggable though. you might have to roll your own if you want simplicity

Comment: Also requires jQuery which probably doesn't qualify it as "simple" :)

Comment: Thanks for reply <br/> Ryley - you are right, and it's not draggable

Comment: i guess it depends on how much JS you plan to use in your project. I think that after a certain amount of JS, you are better off writing it with jquery. minified core is like 50k. thats not very much in 2010